# Pycharm 2020.1. Version Getting Error While Lunching

Tags: pycharm

[image]

Getting this Error While Lunching.

OS Version: Ubuntu 18.04
Pycharm Version: 2020.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you didn't use Toolbox to install PyCharm remove `~/.local/share/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/marketplace`. See the relevant ticket in JetBrains bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237012